# Why is ping timing out from WebServer01 to DBServer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have created a Custom VPC using the Terraform code below.

I have applied the Terraform module below, which:

1. Adds Public and Private Subnets
2. Configures IGW
3. Adds NAT Gateway
4. Adds SGs for both Web and DB Servers

After applying this, I am not able to ping/ssh from public ec2 instance to the private ec2 instance.

Not sure what is missing.

```
# Custom VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "MyVPC" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default" # For Prod use "dedicated"

  tags = {
    Name = "MyVPC"
  }
}

# Creates "Main Route Table", "NACL" & "default Security Group"

# Create Public Subnet, Associate with our VPC, Auto assign Public IP
resource "aws_subnet" "PublicSubNet" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id # Our VPC
  availability_zone       = "eu-west-2a"     # AZ within London, 1 Subnet = 1 AZ
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"    #  Check using this later > "${cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.MyVPC.cidr_block, 4, 1)}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"           # Auto assign Public IP for Public Subnet
  tags = {
    Name = "PublicSubNet"
  }
}

# Create Private Subnet, Associate with our VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "PrivateSubNet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id # Our VPC
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"     # AZ within London region, 1 Subnet = 1 AZ
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"    #  Check using this later > "${cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.MyVPC.cidr_block, 4, 1)}"
  tags = {
    Name = "PrivateSubNet"
  }
}

# Only 1 IGW per VPC
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "MyIGW" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id
  tags = {
    Name = "MyIGW"
  }
}

# New Public route table, so we can keep "default main" route table as Private. Route out to MyIGW
resource "aws_route_table" "MyPublicRouteTable" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id # Our VPC

  route {                    # Route out IPV4
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0" # IPV4 Route Out for all
    # ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"        The parameter destinationCidrBlock cannot be used with the parameter destinationIpv6CidrBlock # IPV6 Route Out for all
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.MyIGW.id # Target : Internet Gateway created earlier
  }
  route {                                           # Route out IPV6
    ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"                        # IPV6 Route Out for all
    gateway_id      = aws_internet_gateway.MyIGW.id # Target : Internet Gateway created earlier
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "MyPublicRouteTable"
  }
}

# Associate "PublicSubNet" with the public route table created above, removes it from default main route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PublicSubNetnPublicRouteTable" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.PublicSubNet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.MyPublicRouteTable.id
}

# Create new security group "WebDMZ" for WebServer
resource "aws_security_group" "WebDMZ" {
  name        = "WebDMZ"
  description = "Allows SSH & HTTP requests"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id # Our VPC : SGs cannot span VPC

  ingress {
    description = "Allows SSH requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]   # SSH restricted to my laptop public IP <My PUBLIC IP>/32
  }
  ingress {
    description = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]   # You can use Load Balancer
  }
  ingress {
    description      = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV6"
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    protocol         = "tcp"
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
  egress {
    description = "Allows SSH requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]   # SSH restricted to my laptop public IP <My PUBLIC IP>/32
  }
  egress {
    description = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    description      = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV6"
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    protocol         = "tcp"
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}

# Create new EC2 instance (WebServer01) in Public Subnet
# Get ami id from Console
resource "aws_instance" "WebServer01" {
  ami           = "ami-01a6e31ac994bbc09"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.PublicSubNet.id
  key_name = "MyEC2KeyPair"   # To connect using key pair
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id]    # Assign WebDMZ security group created above
  # vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "WebServer01"
  }
}

# Create new security group "MyDBSG" for WebServer
resource "aws_security_group" "MyDBSG" {
  name        = "MyDBSG"
  description = "Allows Public WebServer to Communicate with Private DB Server"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id # Our VPC : SGs cannot span VPC

  ingress {
    description = "Allows ICMP requests: IPV4" # For ping,communication, error reporting etc
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]    # Public Subnet CIDR block, can be "WebDMZ" security group id too as below
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id]        # Tried this as above was not working, but still doesn't work
  }
  ingress {
    description      = "Allows SSH requests: IPV4" # You can SSH from WebServer01 to DBServer, using DBServer private ip address and copying private key to WebServer
    from_port        = 22                          # ssh ec2-user@Private Ip Address -i MyPvKey.pem     Private Key pasted in MyPvKey.pem
    to_port          = 22                          # Not a good practise to use store private key on WebServer, instead use Bastion Host (Hardened Image, Secure) to connect to Private DB
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "Allows HTTP requests: IPV4"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  ingress {
    description      = "Allows HTTPS requests : IPV4"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  ingress {
    description      = "Allows MySQL/Aurora requests"
    from_port        = 3306
    to_port          = 3306
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  egress {
    description = "Allows ICMP requests: IPV4" # For ping,communication, error reporting etc
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"] # Public Subnet CIDR block, can be "WebDMZ" security group id too
  }
  egress {
    description      = "Allows SSH requests: IPV4" # You can SSH from WebServer01 to DBServer, using DBServer private ip address and copying private key to WebServer
    from_port        = 22                          # ssh ec2-user@Private Ip Address -i MyPvtKey.pem     Private Key pasted in MyPvKey.pem chmod 400 MyPvtKey.pem
    to_port          = 22                          # Not a good practise to use store private key on WebServer, instead use Bastion Host (Hardened Image, Secure) to connect to Private DB
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  egress {
    description = "Allows HTTP requests: IPV4"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  egress {
    description      = "Allows HTTPS requests : IPV4"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  egress {
    description      = "Allows MySQL/Aurora requests"
    from_port        = 3306
    to_port          = 3306
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
}


# Create new EC2 instance (DBServer) in Private Subnet, Associate "MyDBSG" Security Group
resource "aws_instance" "DBServer" {
  ami           = "ami-01a6e31ac994bbc09"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.PrivateSubNet.id
  key_name = "MyEC2KeyPair"   # To connect using key pair
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.MyDBSG.id] # THIS WAS GIVING ERROR WHEN ASSOCIATING
  # vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.MyDBSG.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "DBServer"
  }
}

# Elastic IP required for NAT Gateway
resource "aws_eip" "nateip" {
  vpc = true
  tags = {
    Name = "NATEIP"
  }
}

# DBServer in private subnet cannot access internet, so add "NAT Gateway" in Public Subnet
# Add Target as NAT Gateway in default main route table. So there is route out to Internet.
# Now you can do yum update on DBServer

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATGW" {         # Create NAT Gateway in each AZ so in case of failure it can use other
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nateip.id          # Elastic IP allocation
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.PublicSubNet.id # Public Subnet

  tags = {
    Name = "NATGW"
  }
}

# Main Route Table add NATGW as Target

resource "aws_default_route_table" "DefaultRouteTable" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.MyVPC.default_route_table_id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"              # IPV4 Route Out for all
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.NATGW.id # Target : NAT Gateway created above
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "DefaultRouteTable"
  }
}
```

Why is ping timing out from WebServer01 to DBServer?

Comment: I'm going to attempt to figure this out. You've done an excellent job of including context and commenting your module, which will help a lot. I reformatted the code so it would highlight properly and I rephrased your question a bit for clarity. Please let me know if I've lost your intent in translation.

Comment: I don't know why you've specified the egress because security groups are stateful and all (allowed) inbound traffic is allowed to get back to you "outbound" with that being said, it looks like you've specified the ICMP port as -1 instead of 1?
Also if it is the webserver that needs to talk to the Db then have the Webserver SecurityGroup as a source in the Db Security group instead of specifying a fixed IP

Comment: @photowalker that's not way it works. If a security group does not explictly allow traffic it is implicitly denied. If a security group for the source does not have a rule allowing the destination IP or SG with the matching protocol and port either directly or as part of a broader rule, the traffic won't be allowed.

Comment: And -1 for port means all ICMP types, which is the OP's intent.

Comment: @photowalker to clarify, it isn't statefulness thing here, it's a matching inbound and outbound stateful rule thing. ENI A with SG A can reach a service on protocol X, port Y, on ENI B with SG B if and only if SG A allows the initiation to SG B or the ENI's IP on protocol X port Y in its outbound rules and SG B allows the initiation from SG A or ENI A's IP on protocol X port Y in its inbound rules. If SG A has no outbound rules, ENI A cannot initiate any flows in the VPC on any protocol or port. If SG A has inbound rules, it can accept flows initiated from other ENIs matching those rules.

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to activate Ping/ICMP? Typically, people use Ping to debug their network configuration, but in the end all it proves is that ICMP works, rather than having their _actual desired_ network connection working. For example, your goal might be for an EC2 instance in the public subnet to be able to communicate with a database in the private subnet. If so, you should concentrate on getting that configuration to work, rather than trying to get ICMP to work. So, what is your _actual_ goal here? Can your web server currently connect to the database _for database queries_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no specific NACLs and the default NACLs are wide open, so they should not be relevant here.

For this to work the security group on **DBServer** needs to allow egress to the security group of **DBServer** or to a CIDR that includes it.

**aws_instance.DBServer** uses **aws_security_group.MyDBSG**.

**aws_instance.WebServer01** uses **aws_security_group.WebDMZ**.

The egress rules on **aws_security_group.WebDMZ** are as follows:

```
  egress {
    description = "Allows SSH requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]   # SSH restricted to my laptop public IP <My PUBLIC IP>/32
  }
  egress {
    description = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    description      = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV6"
    from_port        = 80
    to_port          = 80
    protocol         = "tcp"
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
```

Those egress rules mean:

1. Allow SSH to all IPv4 hosts
2. Allow HTTP to all IPv4 and IPv6 hosts

ICMP isn't listed, so the ICMP echo request will be dropped before it leaves **aws_security_group.WebDMZ**. This should be visible as a REJECT in the VPC FlowLog for the ENI of **aws_instance.WebServer01**.

Adding this **egress** rule to **aws_security_group.WebDMZ** should fix that:

```
  egress {
    description      = "Allows ICMP requests: IPV4" # For ping,communication, error reporting etc
    from_port        = -1
    to_port          = -1
    protocol         = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  }
```

DBServer may NOT respond to ICMP, so you may still see timeouts after making this change. Referencing the VPC FlowLog will help determine the difference. If you see ACCEPTs in the VPC FlowLog for the ICMP flows, then the issue is that DBServer doesn't respond to ICMP.

Nothing in **aws_security_group.WebDMZ** prevents SSH, so the problem with that must be elsewhere.

The ingress rules on **aws_security_group.MyDBSG** are as follows.

```
  ingress {
    description = "Allows ICMP requests: IPV4" # For ping,communication, error reporting etc
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]    # Public Subnet CIDR block, can be "WebDMZ" security group id too as below
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id]        # Tried this as above was not working, but still doesn't work
  }
  ingress {
    description      = "Allows SSH requests: IPV4" # You can SSH from WebServer01 to DBServer, using DBServer private ip address and copying private key to WebServer
    from_port        = 22                          # ssh ec2-user@Private Ip Address -i MyPvKey.pem     Private Key pasted in MyPvKey.pem
    to_port          = 22                          # Not a good practise to use store private key on WebServer, instead use Bastion Host (Hardened Image, Secure) to connect to Private DB
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
```

Those egress rules mean:

1. Allow all ICMP from the Public Subnet (10.0.1.0/24)
2. Allow SSH from the Public Subnet (10.0.1.0/24)

SSH should be working. DBServer likely does not accept SSH connections.

Assuming your DBServer is 10.0.2.123, then if SSH is not running it would look like this from WebServer01 running `ssh -v 10.0.2.123`:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.2.123 [10.0.2.123] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.2.123 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.123 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Referencing the VPC FlowLog will help determine the difference. If you see ACCEPTs in the VPC FlowLog for the SSH flows, then the issue is that DBServer doesn't accept SSH connections.

## Enabling VPC Flow Logs

Since this has changed a few times over the years, I will point you to [AWS' own maintained, step by step guide for creating a flow log that publishes to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-cwl.html#flow-logs-cwl-create-flow-log).

I recommend CloudWatch over S3 at the moment since querying using CloudWatch Logs Insights is pretty easy compared to setting up and querying S3 with Athena. You just pick the CloudWatch Log Stream you used for your Flow Log and search for the IPs or ports of interest.

This example CloudWatch Logs Insights query will get the most recent 20 rejects on eni-0123456789abcdef0 (not a real ENI, use the actual ENI ID you are debugging):

```
fields @timestamp,@message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @message like 'eni-0123456789abcdef0'
| filter @message like 'REJECT'
| limit 20
```

In the VPC Flow Log a missing egress rule shows up as a REJECT on the source ENI.

In the VPC Flow Log a missing ingress rule shows up as a REJECT on the destination ENI.

## Security Groups are stateful

Stateless packet filters require you to handle arcane things like the fact that most (not all) OSes use ports 32767-65535 for reply traffic in TCP flows. That's a pain, and it makes NACLs (which a stateless) a huge pain.

A stateful firewall like Security Groups tracks connections (the state in stateful) automatically, so you just need to allow the service port to the destination's SG or IP CIDR block in the source SG's egress rules and from the source SG or IP CIDR block in the destination SG's ingress rules.

Even though Security Groups (SGs) are stateful, they are default deny. This includes the outbound initiated traffic from a source. If a source SG does not allow traffic outbound to a destination, it's not allowed even if the destination has an SG that allows it. This is a common misconception. SG rules are not transitive, they need to be made on both sides.

[AWS's Protecting Your Instance with Security Groups video](https://www.aws.training/Details/Video?id=16487) explains this very well and visually.

## Aside: Style recommendation

You should use [**aws_security_group_rule**](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group_rule.html) resources instead of inline egress and ingress rules.

> NOTE on Security Groups and Security Group Rules: Terraform currently provides both a standalone Security Group Rule resource (a single ingress or egress rule), and a Security Group resource with ingress and egress rules defined in-line. At this time you cannot use a Security Group with in-line rules in conjunction with any Security Group Rule resources. Doing so will cause a conflict of rule settings and will overwrite rules.

Take this old-style **aws_security_group** with inline rules:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "WebDMZ" {
  name        = "WebDMZ"
  description = "Allows SSH & HTTP requests"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]   # You can use Load Balancer
  }

  egress {
    description = "Allows SSH requests for VPC: IPV4"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

And replace it with this modern-style **aws_security_group** with **aws_security_group_rule** resources for each rule:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "WebDMZ" {
  name        = "WebDMZ"
  description = "Allows SSH & HTTP requests"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.MyVPC.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "WebDMZ_HTTP_in" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id

  type        = "ingress"
  description = "Allows HTTP requests for VPC: IPV4"
  from_port   = 80
  to_port     = 80
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "WebDMZ_SSH_out" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.WebDMZ.id

  type        = "egress"
  description = "Allows SSH requests for VPC: IPV4"
  from_port   = 22
  to_port     = 22
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Comment: @Mahesh if this works for you, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton Alain. You have explained it perfectly and to the point . Thanks again for the modern style recommendation. I have 2 further questions and I will close the post. 1) This should be visible as a REJECT in the VPC FlowLog for the ENI of aws_instance.WebServer01  ? Mahesh : How do I enable flow log to check this? 2) For new modern "security group rule", do I need to explicitly mention both ingress and egress rules OR since SGs are stateful, egress would be automatically created ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to link to a good resource on VPC Flow Log and provide some hints on using it. I've also included a section on the statefulness of security groups. This is frequently misunderstood and I've done my best to explain it. I've also linked to a great AWS video on security groups with good visual explanations.

Comment: @Mahesh any luck? Did my edits resolve your remaining concerns?

Comment: Hi @Alain Yes I was able to resolve. It was simple miss from my side on the egress rule for WebDMZ security group. Also the old style "aws_security_group" is better then the new style "aws_security_group_rule" because in former you can specify both ingress and egress inline , where as in later you would need to type in each rule seperately. Many thanks for your help. Have a nice week ahead !

Comment: @Mahesh for a sense of the pain continuing to use inline rules will cause you, take a look at this answer and the question that inspired it. Save yourself future headaches by switching styles before you become too comfortable with the inline approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458499/154527

Answer (score 0):

Allowing all outbound rules from "WebDMZ" security group as pasted below resolves the issue.

```
egress {  # Allow allow traffic outbound, THIS WAS THE REASON YOU WAS NOT ABLE TO PING FROM WebServer to DBServer
    description = "Allows All Traffic Outbound from Web Server" 
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }
```